# Using guice when creating a custom Action using ActionBuilder in play

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

How can I use guice when creating a custom Action using ActionBuilder?

It seems to complain with "not found: value MyAction" if I change the ActionBuilder from a object to a class.

I have this but it doesn't work:

```
case class MyModel(name: String, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

class MyAction @Inject()(userService: UserService) extends ActionBuilder[MyModel] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (MyModel[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
    val abc = loadAbc(request)
    block(new MyModel(abc, request))
  }

  def loadAbc(rh: RequestHeader): String {
    "abc" // just for testing
  }
}
```

So changing it from an `object` to a `class` causes it to fail, and I tried keeping it as an object but then it doesn't compile correctly.

How can I get this to work?

I have it working just fine in my controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a few minor corrections, what you've got seems to work already.  All you've got to do is inject the guice-instantiated instance of `MyAction` into your controller, and then you can use the instance (rather than trying to use the `MyAction` class name).

This works with Play 2.3:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.mvc._

class UserService() {
  def loadAbc(rh: RequestHeader) = "abc"
}

class MyModel[A](val name: String, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

class MyAction @Inject()(userService: UserService) extends ActionBuilder[MyModel] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (MyModel[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
    val abc = userService.loadAbc(request)
    block(new MyModel(abc, request))
  }
}

@Singleton
class Application @Inject() (myAction: MyAction) extends Controller {
  def index = myAction { request =>
    Ok(request.name)
  }
}
```

You can't use `object` because that violates the design of Guice.  `object` is a singleton instantiated by Scala itself and cannot have instance variables, whereas Guice needs to be able to instantiate classes on the fly so that it can inject dependencies.

Comment: I'm not sure what I was doing but I must have been using the class name instead of the instance in my action.  thanks!

Comment: Hi, what if I want to add a parameter to MyAction?  I can't seem to do it e.g. `class MyAction(id: Int = 1) @Inject ....`  Am I doing something wrong or it isn't possible?

Comment: Add your parameter within the `(userService: UserService)` list

Comment: I want to add the parameter in my controller like:  `MyAction("hello" { request => ... }`

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should work if you use it like this:

```
class MyClass @Inject()(myAction: MyAction) {
  val echo = myAction { request =>
    Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
  }
}
```

Comment: Originally my custom action was an 'object', can I keep it that way?  Is it instantiated per request?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to use Guice with `object`. But if you want the same instance to be used every time, you can use Guice's `@Singleton` annotation above the definition of `MyAction`.