# How can I chain my custom actions when using ActionBuilder

Tags: scala, playframework

Trying to better understand creating custom actions using action builder.

I have a custom action like:

```
class LogginInRequest[A](val currentUser: User, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

object ActionWithContext extends ActionBuilder[LogginInRequest] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (LogginInRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
    val u = /// load User
    block(new LogginInRequest(user, request)
  }
}
```

1. Could I someone create another custom action like the above that inherits from the above one and builds upon it i.e. chain in the action and access the user object

   e.g. Say I now create a new section on my website for admins, so I check the user object in this new action for:
    user.isAdmin

   If isAdmin is false, then I redirect using the `Future.successful(Forbidden)` call.

   So I would create LoggedInAdmin based on LogginInRequest but simply checking for the property isAdmin (this is just an example but I want to know if I can do this).
2. Is it possible to pass an argument to my custom action that I created using action builder so I can do this?

   def  someAction(...):=  MyCustomActionBuilder(userService) {
      // ...
   }

i.e. I am passing in a argument to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Play 2.3, action composition using ActionBuilder got a whole lot better.  The example below shows how you can define a standard `ActionBuilder` that creates a wrapped request, and then chain that builder together with an `ActionTransformer` to create a new wrapped request.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

import org.scalatest.{MustMatchers, WordSpec}

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.test.FakeRequest
import play.api.test.Helpers._

class ChainingTest extends WordSpec with MustMatchers {

  class WrappedReq1[A](val str: String, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

  object ActionWithReq1 extends ActionBuilder[WrappedReq1] {
    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (WrappedReq1[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
      block(new WrappedReq1(request.headers("1"), request))
    }
  }

  class WrappedReq2[A](val str1: String, val str2: String, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

  val ActionWithReq2 = ActionWithReq1 andThen new ActionTransformer[WrappedReq1, WrappedReq2] {
    override protected def transform[A](request: WrappedReq1[A]): Future[WrappedReq2[A]] = {
      Future.successful(new WrappedReq2[A](request.str, request.headers("2"), request))
    }
  }

  "chained actions" should {
    "work" in {
      val request = FakeRequest().withHeaders("1" -> "one", "2" -> "two")
      val response = ActionWithReq2 { r => Results.Ok(r.str1 + "-" + r.str2) }(request)
      contentAsString(response) must equal("one-two")
    }
  }
}
```

There is an `ActionTransformer` trait for modifying your request wrapper, and an `ActionFilter` for intercepting certain requests and immediately returning a result.

[ScalaActionsComposition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition) describes the traits in more detail.

Comment: btw, is it possible to use IoC with custom actions?  I'm stuck: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965449/using-guice-when-creating-a-custom-action-using-actionbuilder-in-play